# Is it possible to delete temp files and cache of other apps programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, memory, ram, temp

I have gone through a lot questions regarding cleaning of temp files and cache programmatically and the answer that I got was `No its not possible` since the apps are in sand box mode we can't access content of one app from other except for some scenarios where we have read permission.But recently I got to see one app which is removing **temporary files of other apps**. It is live and approved by apple.

Below is the screen shot of the alert that it gives when user asks for **Deleting Temp Files**.

[image]

So my question is that is deleting Temp files and cache of other apps is possible programmatically now or is there any particular device location from where we can clear the temp-files or cache of all the apps.I am confused between What I see (the cleaning app) and what I read that its not possible (the previous stack overflow questions and blogs). Some valuable links and comments are appreciated.

Comment: There is always a possibility that the company got special permission to do it. Its very rare and takes and act of God but its (special permissions) been done (at least from what I have heard).

Comment: What if that app uses standard calloc/free functions? Just allocating as much memory, as possible and freeing. I have seen such app too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like the app tries to fill all available memory (random access or disk), relays on the OS to free more resources and repeats it several times trying to be as fail safe as possible at the same time, i.e. balancing on the edge when you may request more resources than is available. On paper it should work but as you can imagine that is not how the resources are meant to be optimised on a regular basis.

Comment: @logixologist..What kind of special permission?Is it a permission from apple side or something else.Can you please tell what you have heard about it in a bit detail.

Comment: @kelin...Actually we have also created an app which was filling memory as what A-Live is suggesting and then memory was freeing but that was rejected by the apple.I don't know how they accept sometimes even if it is a fake call or doing something that is not allowed by apple.

Comment: @A-Live....We have three scenarios here i.e. RAM,junk and other app temp files.If we leave RAM as we know by filling of memory as what he is trying what about the other two.

Comment: The most obvious answer is that despite what the app is saying, it's not actually deleting files in other apps' sand boxes.  It's either a lie, or a different interpretation.

Comment: So what do you think what kind of cleaning may be going.Is there any scope of clearing temp files,cache or junks at some location in the device directly accessible to the developers?

Comment: @A-Live, I think, it should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Imran I can only assume that your app was declaring resources optimisation as one of the main features while the other app main feature is said to be available resources monitoring which is the only acceptable way as the optimisation is not guaranteed to work. As for the temp ("junk" is too strong word IMO) files - [same story](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) as  with the RAM.

Comment: @A-Live So what do you think its all like filling the memory intentionally and forcing the OS to release the memory is it the same case he is using for temp files too.

Comment: @Imran yes I believe so, it matches the alert notifying about the "Disk almost full" messages, not sure why you removed this screenshot.

Comment: @A-LiveI removed it because my main question is about temp files and cache.Regarding filling of disk we have already done one app months ago and that was rejected by apple for some reason but now I can see similar apps are in app store.The thing that is troubling is about temp files.In sand box mode apple has directly written that we cant even touch the other apps temp files and this app claiming the same and been approved by apple.People here are asking me that if one app is doing then its possible todo and I am still unable to get to the conclusion.please suggest me if u have any idea.Thanks

Comment: A-Live is right. You can't touch other apps' files, but iOS can. And if your app keeps asking for more and more disk space, iOS will remove other apps' temp files. Then you can just free all the space iOS gave you and here you go: temp files are gone. I saw a similar discussion about such apps (for "freeing the memory") before somewhere, and that's how they work. To sum up: you can't get access to other apps' files, but you can trick the OS into deleting them.

Comment: @FreeNickname...Do you have the link you read.It will be great help.Also any idea about iPhone memory optimization.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help.I got to know much about it.Please give a balanced answer concluded from all your comments  so that I can accept this and close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this app probably uses a technique that over-damands disk space in order to force iOS to delete temp files system wide and in other apps, if it was noticed by the reviewer it would have been rejected by the appstore. It is further likely that it will be removed from sale at a later time. I have had such things happen with apps that i developed which 'bend the rules'. I would not recommend investing any development time into apps that Apple are highly likely to reject or remove from sale.